# how can i move hamburger menu to right side on maui android?

Tags: maui

I am making android/ios app using maui.
I want to move my hamburger button to right side.

this is my appshell.xaml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiSample.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiSample.Views"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiSample"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

    <FlyoutItem
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Dog2s"
                            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Monkeys"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Elephants"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Bears"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home 2"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

I check added supportRtl="true" in android manifest.
android:supportsRtl="true"

I used FlowDirection="RightToLeft".
but not working on android.
working on ios.

[image: android]

[image: ios]

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63498743/724039 ?

Comment: #Luuk thank you your comment. but this link is for web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your MainActivity.cs:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{    
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
    {        
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);        
       Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = Android.Views.LayoutDirection.Rtl;    
    }
}
```

Comment: For more things, you can refer to this doc: [LayoutDirection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection) by official.